# How to retain multiple occurrences of same string get selected within same styled text content?

Tags: java, swt, styledtext

How to retain multiple occurrences of same string get selected within same styled text content? Single occurrence can be selected using `setSelection()`. Is there any similar options?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `StyleRange` to set multiple occurrences of the string.

Snippet:

```
    String searchKey = "hello";
    String content = styledText.getText(); // StyledText instance
    int index = content.indexOf(searchKey, 0);
    do {
        if (index != -1) {
            StyleRange styleRange = new StyleRange(index, searchKey.length(), Display.getCurrent().getSystemColor(
                    SWT.COLOR_BLACK), Display.getCurrent().getSystemColor(SWT.COLOR_YELLOW));
            styledText.setStyleRange(styleRange);
            index = content.indexOf(searchKey, index + 1);
        } else {
            System.out.println("End of search");
            break;
        }

    } while (index != -1);
```

Refer [this](http://www.eclipse.org/articles/StyledText%201/article1.html) article an [examples here](http://www.java2s.com/Tutorial/Java/0280__SWT/UseriseandfontwithStyleRange.htm) on style ranges.

Comment: Thanks for your valuable suggestion.But I want to just set all occurance of a string got selected.I have already implemented the case that you have explained above.

Comment: No its not possible. `In any text editor you can select only ONE RANGE of text(From character index n to character index n+/-x) not multiple at a given time`. But  you can highlight the search terms in editors by changing the background and foreground colour.